# Rails ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord when after updating belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, readonly

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :model2

 after_create :update_model_to

 def update_model_to
    model2.increment!(:some_val)
 end
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :model1s
end
```

If I update model2 after_create, suddenly I get readonly errors in my specs:

```
 ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord:
       ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord

The error: 
 ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord:
       ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:480:in `create_or_update'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
     #/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__425188915132088351__save__callbacks'
     #/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
     #/airbrake-5.7.1/lib/airbrake/rails/active_record.rb:22:in `run_callbacks'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:330:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:327:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:220:in `update_attribute'
     #/activerecord-4.0.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:300:in `increment!'
     # ./app/models/model1.rb:256:in `update_model_to'
```

Not sure what is happening here. I get the error for all specs that are trying to modify model1 or model2.

Comment: What do you need to `increment` that is associated values count number?

Comment: Do you really want to increment a value each time model1 was saved ? Is the error really comming from the update_mode_to method ?

Comment: Yes, I do need to increment it everytime model1 is saved. I added the spec error log in my question. What I think is happening is that the model1 or model2 becomes readonly and the specs can modify the model because of that.

Comment: I don't really know sth about the increment! but my update_model_to would look like `self.model2.update_attributes(some_val: self.model2.some_val + 1)`

Comment: I am having a similar problem, using update_attribute (not increment), do you remember how you solved it?